# Angular 6 ngFor keyvalue & sort

Tags: angular, sorting, ngfor

How i can add sorting by for example: section0.value.order I can not combine

> keyvalue

with sorting ;/

Comment: can you post something that you've tried so for  and the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: I would recommend start with reading this article first.[link](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)
Please specify your question next time with more details and code you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
  <li *ngFor="let section2 of section1.value.modules | keyvalue">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">{{section2.value.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have a sorted server response (json) but *ngFor makes a different order.

Comment: I can write orderBy:section1.value.order:ascending before  | keyvalue ?